# How should i extract text from pdf to csv on the basis of coordinates using python?

Tags: python, ocr, export-to-csv, python-tesseract, text-extraction

```
import pdfquery
import pandas as pd

pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery('HBL.PDF')
pdf.load()
pdf.tree.write('pdfXML.xml', pretty_print = True)

def pdfscrape(pdf):
    # Extract each relevant information individually
    shipper = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("33.0, 756.181, 281.4, 787.659")').text()
    consignee = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("33.0, 650.454, 281.4, 704.409")').text()
    notify_party = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("33.0, 612.909, 124.8, 621.909")').text()
    ocean_vessel = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("33.75, 518.409, 147.15, 527.409")').text()
    port_of_loading = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("164.25, 518.409, 245.25, 527.409")').text()
    port_of_discharge = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("33.75, 495.159, 103.95, 504.159")').text()
    place_of_delivery = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("164.25, 497.409, 234.45, 506.409")').text()
    for_delivery_of_goods = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("286.5, 549.219, 507.9, 618.159")').text()
    container_no_and_seal_no = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("54.75, 455.409, 92.55, 464.409")').text()
    no_of_container = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("164.25, 454.659, 223.65, 463.659")').text()
    gross_weight = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("432.75, 455.409, 475.95, 464.409")').text()
    measurement = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("502.5, 447.916, 534.9, 464.409")').text()
# Combined all relevant information into single observation
    page = pd.DataFrame({
                         'Shipper': shipper,
                         'Consignee': consignee,
                         'Notify_party': notify_party,
                         'Ocean_vessel': ocean_vessel,
                         'Port_of_loading': port_of_loading,
                         'port_of_discharge': port_of_discharge,
                         'place_of_delivery': place_of_delivery,
                         'for_delivery_of_goods': for_delivery_of_goods,
                         'container_no_and_seal_no': container_no_and_seal_no,
                         'no_of_container': no_of_container,
                         'gross_weight': gross_weight,
                         'measurement': measurement
                       }, index=[0])
    return(page)

pagecount = pdf.doc.catalog['Pages'].resolve()['Count']
master = pd.DataFrame()
for p in range(pagecount):
    pdf.load(p)
    page = pdfscrape(pdf)
    master = master.append(page, ignore_index=True)

master.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

`

`

I have extracted text in CSV format after converting it to xml file. And, on the basis of coordinates I am converting it to csv. But, here I am putting coordinates after checking xml manually. As, it can be different for other pdf. So, I want to use coordinates dynamically (directly from xml file).

[This is the pdf from which I am extracting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtLcM.jpg)

[Here, I am attaching the CSV file in which I am getting a data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB2uP.jpg)

Now, I just want to extract those coordinates from XML file directly. I do not want to put those coordinates manually inside code.

Comment: coordinates of what?  What is the result of your line of code ```master = master.append(page, ignore_index=True)'''?

Comment: coordinates of the text in the pdf.

Comment: So it looks like you can extract the data from the pdf, convert the data to a dictionary and write the result to a csv.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Sir, my problem is that inside "def pdfscrape(pdf):" function. I am using coordinates after seeing it from XML file like this "overlaps_bbox("33.0, 756.181, 281.4, 787.659")".
But, I want to extract it like(x0, y0, x1, y1) in a variable so that i do not need to put the coordinates manually.

Comment: What is wrong with specifying the data locations using the coordinates?  Is it a problem, that the coordinates are not always the same?  If you don't employ coordinates to specify data location, what keywords would you intend to use to distinguish the desired text?

Comment: Exactly, the coordinates I am getting is always different. That is why I want to get it in the format something like this "(%s %s %s %s, x0, y0, x1, y1)". So that I do not require to check the coordinates and put it manually always.

Comment: So what keywords would you use?